Scala Slick - Not Null not working as expected?
I have a slick expression where I want to make sure s.next is not null in conjunction with another condition:
val expiredSchedulesQuery = schedules.filter(s => {
  val expiredSchedule = s.next < currentTime && s.next =!= null.asInstanceOf[null]
  val exceededRuns = s.runs >= s.ttl.asColumnOf[Long]
  val nonZeroTtl = !(s.ttl === 0)
  expiredSchedule || (exceededRuns && !nonZeroTtl)
})

However this query is translating to:
...
WHERE (
      ("NEXT" < 1721815595) 
    AND (not ("NEXT" = 0))
) OR ((
    ("RUNS" >= cast("TTL" as BIGINT)) 
  AND (NOT (NOT ("TTL" = 0)))
))


I want it to be
("NEXT" < 1721815595) and (not ("NEXT" is null))) 

I am using slick 5.2. Can someone point me to the right syntax?
